# How to check that the script has loaded data and render it once in another script Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

First time on StackOverflow and my english is very bad, so I apologize if the question is fool or poorly formulated.
I have a script that loads Scriptable Object data and creates a List with other objects based on it.

```
public class AntContainer : MonoBehaviour
{
    private List<AntType> _types;

    public IEnumerable<AntType> Types { get => _types; } 
    private void Start()
    {
        _types = new List<AntType>();
        List<AntTypeData> data = Resources.LoadAll<AntTypeData>("ScriptableObjects/AntTypes").ToList();
        data = data.OrderBy((x) => x.Price).ToList();

        foreach (var type in data)
        {
            _types.Add(new AntType(type));
        }
    }
}
```

Then I need to draw this List in the UI script

```
public class AntShopPanel : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _antShopElementTemplate;
    [SerializeField] private Transform _parent;
    [SerializeField] private AntNursery _nursery;
    [SerializeField] private AntContainer _container;

    private void Start()
    {
        if (_container != null)
        {
            foreach (var type in _container.Types)
            {
                GameObject AntButton = Instantiate(_antShopElementTemplate, _parent);
                AntShopElementPresenter presenter = AntButton.GetComponent<AntShopElementPresenter>();
                presenter.Present(type);
                presenter.SetBuyButtonOnClick(() => _nursery.AddEgg(type));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, both scripts perform actions in the Start method, so if the UI script is initialized earlier and the data is not loaded, then there will be nothing to draw.
How can I make sure that the data is loaded before the UI script request data? Or how can this problem be solved in a different way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a good rule of thumb to do all of your initialization steps inside of Unity's **[Awake](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Awake.html)** function.

Changing your AntContainer.Start() method to Awake() instead will ensure that everything is initialized before all of your Start functions start getting called.

Like so:

```
public class AntContainer : MonoBehaviour
{
    private List<AntType> _types;

    public IEnumerable<AntType> Types { get => _types; } 
    private void Awake()
    {
        _types = new List<AntType>();
        List<AntTypeData> data = Resources.LoadAll<AntTypeData>("ScriptableObjects/AntTypes").ToList();
        data = data.OrderBy((x) => x.Price).ToList();

        foreach (var type in data)
        {
            _types.Add(new AntType(type));
        }
    }
}
```